# Property Is not like. GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, filter, function, conditional

Which function/condition should I use to get the opposite of "PropertyIsLike" in GeoServer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your `<PropertyIsLike>` element in a `<Not>` element.

So:

```
<ogc:Filter>                                                                                                            
  <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="." escape="!">                                                           
    <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>                                                                         
    <ogc:Literal>*ian*</ogc:Literal>                                                                             
  </ogc:PropertyIsLike>                                                                                                 
</ogc:Filter>
```

becomes:

```
<ogc:Filter>                                                                                                            
  <ogc:Not>                                                                                                             
    <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="." escape="!">                                                         
      <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>                                                                         
      <ogc:Literal>*ian*</ogc:Literal>                                                                                  
    </ogc:PropertyIsLike>                                                                                               
  </ogc:Not>                                                                                                            
</ogc:Filter>
```